# Trying to append a square div inside a bigger square div and make it draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a button and a big div. Upon the button being pressed, the code "appends" a new div inside the big div. That new div appended is then stuck on there because apparently, I didn't make the right code to make it live draggable?

Also, I'm trying to fix it so when they "appended"... that they aren't "stacked" going from up to down... maybe in a random place between the div...

http://jsbin.com/obizel/3/

Here's what I have so far...

Comment: is draggable a problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obizel/13/)** to get you started. Your libraries have been updated, too (out of order before).

Notice that your container(`#box`) must be positioned `relative`ly because the draggable plugin makes your `.new_box`es positioned absolutely. See the CSS for details.

The new JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function createBox($parent, left, top) {
    var $box = $('<div class="new_box">Hello world</div>');
    $box.appendTo($parent);
    $box.draggable({
      containment: $parent,
      grid: [10, 10]
    });
    $box.css({
      left: left,
      top: top
    });
  }

  $(".add").click(function (e) {
    var $container = $("#box"),
      w = $container.width(),
      h = $container.height();

    createBox($container, Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your libraries are our of kilter. I changed them from:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So, it looks like you had a mismatch and you were loading the same library twice. All works when you change those lines.